# Dependent picklist

Tags: apex

```
        I have two picklists A and B. I want the picklist B values should change depends on the picklist A selection.
    Below is VF page code

    <apex:page standardController="object1__c" extensions="DPicklist">
        <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlock title="Create New Deal Registrarion">
                <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save" style="background:#1AC421"/>
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel" style="background:#F12F18"/>
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <pageBlock>
                    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="3">
                        <apex:selectList value="{!SelectedNames}" style="width:30%" size="1" > Picklist A :
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!ListOfManufacturers}" />
                        </apex:selectList>
                        <apex:selectList style="width:30%"   size="1"> Picklist B :
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!ListOfFormNames}" />
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </pageBlock>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

And the Controller is

```
 public with sharing class DRegPicklist {

        public String SelectedNames{set; get;}
        public DReg__c obj;
        String manufacturerName;
        List<SelectOption> ManufacturerOptionList = new List<SelectOption>();
        public DRegPicklist(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
            this.obj= (DReg__c)controller.getRecord(); 
        }

            public List<SelectOption> getListOfManufacturers(){
                List<DR_Program__c> ManufacturertList = [select id,Manufacturer__r.name,isActive__c from obj1 where isActive__c=true] ;
                ManufacturerOptionList .add(new SelectOption( ' ' ,'---Select---'));
                for(obk1 drpc : ManufacturertList ){
                    ManufacturerOptionList .add(new SelectOption(drpc.id , drpc.Manufacturer__r.name));
                }
                return ManufacturerOptionList ;
            }

            public List<SelectOption> getListOfFormNames(){
                List<DR_Program__c> formNamesList=[select id,Name,isActive__c from DR_Program__c where Manufacturer__r.name=:SelectedNames];
                List<SelectOption> formNamesOptionList=new List<SelectOption>();
                formNamesOptionList.add(new SelectOption(' ','---Select---'));
                for(obj1 drpcFormNames : formNamesList){
                    formNamesOptionList.add(new SelectOption(drpcFormNames.id,drpcFormNames.Name));
                }
                return formNamesOptionList;
            }
        }
```

can any one help me where am doing mistake.!
Thank you..!

Comment: are these fields setup as dependent picklist in object?

Comment: They are two different picklists..but i want second picklist should display the list depends on first picklist

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an actionSupport event so that the new values are queried when the picklist changes:

```
                    <apex:selectList value="{!SelectedNames}" style="width:30%" size="1" > Picklist A :
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!ListOfManufacturers}" />
                    <apex:actionSupport reRender="form" event="onchange" />
                    </apex:selectList>
```

Since you're already using a getter to render the lists, this should work as you expect.

Comment: No it not working as expected.

Comment: @Peeter6264 Did you add the "form" Id value e.g. `<apex:form id="form">`?

Comment: yes i added.
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!ListOfManufacturers}" />
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="wrapper" />
                    </apex:selectList>
                    <apex:selectList > Form Name :
                    <apex:selectOptions id="wrapper" value="{!ListOfFormNames}"/>

Comment: @Peeter6264 Suggest you put the Id on a parent element not the element itself. Use your browser's Developer Tools Network tab to confirm the request is being made on the change and to see the HTML that comes back.